# Facebook page plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm creating a website and I want to implement FB page of the company on it, but I cannot get it to work. All I see is the name of the page displayed when I load the page. I've got code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin, and I got two blocks of code to use, first one is script, I've tried putting it before, inside and after body element. The second block of code is supposed to be put where I want it to appear on page. Please tell me if you get why this isn't displaying correctly.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>


<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-         width="320" data-height="450" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Comment: Please add some of your code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: "Please tell me if you get why this isn't displaying correctly" how, we can't see your code

Comment: I added ode generated by facebook

Comment: Are you calling your website via HTTP, or are you just viewing it in the browser via the local file system? When doing the latter, the code from FB won’t work as-is, because of the protocol-relative URL they are using to embed their SDK.

Answer (score -1):

Having the same issue.

After putting in the code correctly, I'm viewing the web URL with my browser but still all I see is the name and link of the page.

Is there no one who knows how to fix this??

Comment: It wouldn't let me post a comment. Said something about an account restriction.

Comment: this should be posted inside the comment section